# How to implement a "circuit breaker" for an air cylinder

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, sensor, switches, adc

Basically I have a machine connected to the end of an air cylinder, a paint mixer to be specific. I want to implement some kind of device that won't allow the mixer to be turned on until the air cylinder is fully extended, I was thinking maybe a tripping mechanism that closes the circuit when it reaches full length. I'm not an electrical engineer so I'm sure circuit breaker is probably the wrong term but I was hoping for guidance on what to look for and where to find it! Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like you want something mechanical, not electrical

Comment: If you have not purchased your pneumatic cylinder yet, you can order it with optional reed switches installed. Then you can take the signals from there.

Comment: and if you already have the cylinder,  you could search for "Limit Switch"

Comment: +1 on comments from Tyler and Marla.  Another option might be a pressure switch on the pneumatic feed line.

Comment: I'd suggest migrating this to engineering.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4):

The term that you are most likely looking for is: "limit switch".

There are many options.

1) You can purchase pneumatic cylinders with internal switches that activate when the rod reaches the end of travel.

These switches can handle only a small amount of current and you will need to buffer the signal in some fashion. A relay will work well.

2) Use an external limit switch. Again, there are many choices - it might be a microswitch (with roller lever) or a magnet attached to the mechanism that then operates a magnetic reed switch.

Depending on the physical layout of the machine and how easy it is for someone to make accidental contact with the limit switch, you may need to use a low-voltage circuit that then activates a relay or contactor that controls the mixer.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a cylinder with a magnetic piston. There are "cylinder position switches" available that mount on the outside of the cylinder and can be positioned along the outside of the cylinder to detect when the piston is close to the required position. Some cylinders have a dovetail on the outside to accept a switch, with others you will have to use a clamping arrangement. Old style switches were magnetic reed capsules, however you can get electronic switches such as GMR switches. Below is an example from [this](http://www.automationdirect.com/static/specs/nitracps9dcylposswitch.pdf) supplier:

[image]

Be sure to take safety considerations into account- if there is a possibility of injury if the switch malfunctions you will likely have to add redundancy (maybe the pressure switch will work), and there are things you can do to ensure the switch is actually changing state rather than being stuck on.